# Convert the Rssi value of Beacon to array

Tags: arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I'm planning to convert the output value of the specific beacon (Beacon 1 to 4) that I have scanned into an array like below:

[image]

By using the code below, I able to save the value into a random Rssi number but not into an array. Does anyone know on how to do that in Java

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the RSSI readings into a mutable array list for each minor you encounter.

Add this to your class's ctor:

```
Map<Int, ArrayList> map = new HashMap<Int, ArrayList>();
```

Append RSSI readings like so:

```
if (!map.containsKey(b.getMinor()) {
    map.put(b.getMinor(), new ArrayList<Int>());
}
map.get(b.getMinor()).add(b.getRssi());
```